# check the given date present between fromdate and todate

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataview

I want to check the given date present in from date and todate using dataview row filter expression. For example the input date is 04-13-2012 from date column having 04-01-2012 and the corresponding todate column having the value 04-14-2012. I want to check the date 04-13-2012 present between the two columns using expression.

My code is below..

```
 employee = ListBox1.Items[i].Text;
  DataSet4TableAdapters.sp_getallattendancesetupTableAdapter TA1 = new
               DataSet4TableAdapters.sp_getallattendancesetupTableAdapter();
  DataSet4.sp_getallattendancesetupDataTable DS1 = TA1.GetData();
  DataView DV = new DataView();
  DV = DS1.DefaultView;
  DV.RowFilter = "fldemployee='" + 
  employee + 
  "' and fldfromdate >= #" + 
  txttdate.Text + 
  "#  and fldtodate =#" + 
  txttdate.Text + "#";
```

But its not working how  can i fix this error. please help me to fix this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be typo. (<=)

```
DV.RowFilter = "fldemployee='" + employee + 
"' and fldfromdate >= #" + 
txttdate.Text + 
"#  and fldtodate <=#" + 
txttdate.Text + "#";
```

Comment: Take a look at -> fldtodate<=#" + txtdate.Text + "#";

Comment: I think u mentioned below like this .DV.RowFilter = "fldemployee='" + employee + "' and fldfromdate >= #" + txttdate.Text + "#  and fldtodate <=#" + txttdate.Text + "#";